# Is e (COR) defined for whole situation or just during collision

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, velocity, collision, relative-motion

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution)
$${\text{Coefficient  of  restitution }}(e)={\frac {\left|{\text{Relative  velocity  after  collision}}\right|}{\left|{\text{Relative  velocity  before  collision}}\right|}}$$
where relative velocities should be taken along line of impact

But does this relative velocity include effect of other forces than of collision, i.e. using it during calculation in a collision problem, should it signify whole situation or just the collision part.

suppose during a collision, i have restricted a body to move only in horizontal plane (by providing impulsive forces). so for coefficient of restitution of collision what should be considered,  final original velocity of body, or the velocity it would have had if there were no restrictions?

[image]